# i made a OnTriggerEnter2D void but not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collision, void

hi i made a OnTriggerEnter2D void but not work

i added rigidbody2d in player how will trigger the shop

and there is a box collider and is trigger in player and shop

but not work

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenShop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ShopGui;
    public bool test = false;


    void Update()
    {
        if (test == true)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.tag == "Shop")
        {
            test = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[shop properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJfHY.png)

[player properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Woe.png)

Comment: `OnCollisionEnter2D` != `OnTriggerEnter2D` ... also is there a `BoxCollider` or `BoxCollider2D`?

Comment: BoxCollider2D no 3d and i use OnTriggerEnter2D and OnCollisionEnter2D and not working

Comment: Also just btw .. why having the `Update` and `test` and not simply do `if(collision.transform.CompareTag("Shop")) { Destroy(gameObject); }` ?

Comment: i made test value public and see in the game if test value is true then the collision works only this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `BoxCollider` on `Player` and keep the second one that has Is Trigger Enabled. Use this code **ON THE SHOP**

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        test = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you you fixed the error i will upvote you edit sorry i cant vote i need 15 tiyroy and things

Comment: No worries! Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You are using `OnCollisionEnter2D` callback.
Change it to `OnTriggerEnter2D` to see if that fixes your problem.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Shop")
    {
        test = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ```using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OpenShop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ShopGui;
    public bool test = false;


    void Update()
    {
        if (test == true)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Shop")
        {
            test = true;
        }
    }
}
```i made this and still not work